# Does DOMPDF support digital signatures?

Tags: php, pdf, opencart, tcpdf, dompdf

I want to add Digital signatures to my pdf form which i generated through Dompdf.
I dont know if it is supported as I have searched and got confused. Some said it could be done by integrating the generated pdf with TCPDF. If so than please guide me.

This is how I am generating the pdf with dompdf. It is a dynamic HTML from another tpl file. I am using open cart.

```
$fp = fopen(DIR_DOWNLOAD . "form.pdf","wb");
$dataHtml = $this->render();

$pdf = new DOMPDF;
$pdf->load_html($dataHtml );
$pdf->render();
fwrite($fp , $pdf->output( array("compress" => 0) ));
fclose($fp );
```

Comment: Maby this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745779/generate-pdf-with-digital-signature.

Comment: @Trybal actually by reading this i got confused that how can we integrated both.. copied from its paragraph 3 of answer 1.. It can 100% parse PDF documents generated by itself or pdf document craeted by any other PHP PDF tool (e.g. FPDF, DOM PDF, mPDF, ..), calculate PDF signature and write back the same signed PDF document. how can we do this

Answer (score 0):

DOMPDF don't have digital signatures. If u can change pdf tool, u can use TCPDF this is better pdf parser i think. Here u are instructions how add digital signatures by TCPDF [TCPDF adding digital signature to the created pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100109/tcpdf-adding-digital-signature-to-the-created-pdf).

Comment: If i use TCPDF it breaks my dynamic output. i have 4 pages in my pdf form when i use DOMPDF but if i use TCPDF it just shows me first two

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue in the DOM PDF library that discusses the digital signature feature request: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/686