# Is it possible to add a signature field in a pdf document using PHP? I haven't to "digital sign" document. I only add a signature field.

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature

I have to generate a PDF document and add a "signature field".

A signature field is a field that allow to third party service to digitally sign document.

Is it possible to do this in PHP with an open source solution ?

I saw https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-signer-manual/create-a-signature-field/.

I try to use tcpdf but i have no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745779/generate-pdf-with-digital-signature

Comment: The OP does not want to sign, he wants to add a signature field in which some other application can sign. Thus, not really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745779/generate-pdf-with-digital-signature

Comment: I suggest that you first do some background check on the [different form specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Forms) (if you haven't yet). Some of the specs are proprietary, and even the open ones are not widely supported in different PDF readers across platforms and devices. In general, except for a very specific case or controlled environment, I would steer away from generating any type of "editable"  PDF.

Answer (score 1):

As you already told that you have already gone through seta sign library documentation [here](http://%20https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-signer-manual/create-a-signature-field/)

using setasign you can create a pdf document or use an existing one to create a digital signature field on it. Below is a code example:-

```
<?php
require_once('library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php');

// create a writer
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('visible-field.pdf', true);
// create a new document instance
$document = new SetaPDF_Core_Document($writer);
// create at least a single page
$document->getCatalog()->getPages()->create(SetaPDF_Core_PageFormats::A4);

// add a field left top with an offset of 10 points
SetaPDF_Signer_SignatureField::add(
        $document,
        'Signature field 1',
        1,
        SetaPDF_Signer_SignatureField::POSITION_LEFT_TOP,
        array('x' => 10, 'y' => -10),
        180,
        70
 );


 // add a field absolutely position on the bottom left with an offset of 10 points
 SetaPDF_Signer_SignatureField::add($document, 'Signature field 1', 1, 10, 10, 180, 70);

 // save and finish
 $document->save()->finish();
```

Note:- Use Adobe Acrobat Reader to open the generated document so you can see the digital signature field on pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Use **https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf**

```
    var image = "" // base 64 image

    var url = patientSignature; // url of the image
        
    // Initialize the XMLHttpRequest and wait until file is loaded
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        // Create a Uint8Array from ArrayBuffer
        var codes = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
    
        // Get binary string from UTF-16 code units
        var bin = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, codes);
    
        // Convert binary to Base64
        var b64 ="data:image/jpg;base64,"+ btoa(bin);
        // console.log(b64); //-> "R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs="
    
        var doc = new jsPDF()
        
        doc.addImage(image, "png", 100, 5, 10, 10);
        doc.addImage(bin, "png", 140, 205, 40, 40);
    
        // doc.addImage("data:image/png;base64,"+dataUrl, "JPEG", 100, 5, 10, 10);
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function(element, renderer){
                return true;
            }
        };
        // All units are in the set measurement for the document
        // This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 15, 10, {
            'width': 170, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save(store_data.patientName+'.pdf');
    };

    // Send HTTP request and fetch file as ArrayBuffer
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.send();     
})
```

Comment: You should consider posting only one answer here which contains both your other text answer (which by itself does not contain a solution and so attracted down votes) and your code example. That being said, though, your code does not appear to do what the original poster asked for, the OP wanted to add an empty AcroForm signature form field, not some wet signature image.

Answer (score -2):

You do not indicate if you are generating the PDF via php or creating an off-line PDF.

If off-line this is an easy process assuming your software allows for signature signing.  Check the software manual.

If creating the PDF via php code, this can be done.  There are several ways that this can be accomplished.  You need to make some decisions about what you want to "capture" with the digital signature.  Do a Google search on "php creating digital signatures"